# onloadeddata in SvelteKit works strange

Tags: video, svelte, onload, sveltekit, preload

I'm trying to preload video. The idea is to load low quality video and display it while high quality video is loading.

On dev mode `onloadeddata` not working at all.
On production mode, after page refresh, `onloadeddata` sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't work.

The video is stored in assets folder.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

  export let
    hdSrcArr = [],
    nonHdSrcArr = []

  let
    refHd = null,
    refSmall = null,
    showLowQualityVideo = true

  onMount(() => {
    if(refSmall && refHd) {
      refSmall.onloadeddata = () => {
        refSmall.style.opacity = 1
        refSmall.disablePictureInPicture = true
      }
      refHd.onloadeddata = () => {
        refHd.currentTime = refSmall.currentTime
        refHd.style.opacity = 1
        refHd.disablePictureInPicture = true
        showLowQualityVideo = false
      }
    }
  })
</script>


{#if showLowQualityVideo}
  <video
      bind:this={refSmall}
      playsinline
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      preload="auto"
  >
    {#each nonHdSrcArr as video}
      <source src={video.video} type={video.type} />
    {/each}
  </video>
{/if}

<video
    bind:this={refHd}
    playsinline
    autoplay
    muted
    loop
    preload="auto"
>
  {#each hdSrcArr as video}
    <source src={video.video} type={video.type} />
  {/each}
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very unidiomatic code, there might be some issue with the event handler being added after the event has already been fired, though I am not sure about this.

You should not use the `on...` properties, instead use the [`on:...`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname) directives. By adding the events directly on the elements, the event handler is added automatically once the element is inserted. Styling should be done by conditionally adding classes via [`class:...`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name).

In general you should need `bind:this` very rarely if at all. In events you can use the event object's `currentTarget` to access the element if you need it.